# Get view from FragmentStatePagerAdapter or Fragment from FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, fragment

I have a problem with fragments. I am trying to get data from a fragment to an activity. I am using a FragmentStatePagerAdapter in my Activity.

The fragment is as follow, it creates some view for a user.

```
class FormFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout._component_main_container, container, false)
        ...
        UICreator.create(context, rootView.entry_container) //creation of the form view ok
        ...
        return rootView
    }

    //public method to get the user input
    fun getUserInputData() : List<Data> {
        return CreationService.getUserInput(view!!.entry_container) //same result with rootView.entry_container
    }

}
```

Here my adapter without the arguments passing and getCount, etc..

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        val fragment = FormFragment()
        return fragment
    }
}
```

And in my activity I tried these to get the current fragment and to get the user data but nothing is working.

```
val fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.view_pager + ":" + view_pager.currentItem) as FormFragment
fragment.getUserInputData() --> NULL


val fragment = viewPagerAdapter.getItem(view_pager.currentItem) as FormFragment
fragment.getUserInputData() --> NULL
```

Do you know a valid solution and effective to get the current fragment and the possibility to get a reference to the linear layout view that holding the user data?

Comment: I may have found a solution, but I don't understand why do I have to maintain an array of the fragments instances? (https://pupli.net/2017/06/05/get-current-fragment-displayed-in-viewpager-on-android/)

Comment: How about using an Activity-scoped ViewModel instead?